# Decoding a class based on encoded value Swift

Tags: json, swift, decoding, codable

I'm trying to decode a specific class based on the contents of the encoded data.

```swift
class Vehicle: Codable {
    enum Kind: Int, Codable {
        case car = 0, motorcycle = 1
    }
    
    let brand: String
    let numberOfWheels: Int
}

class Car: Vehicle {}
class MotorCycle: Vehicle {}
```

As you can see, I have a generic `Vehicle` type used to encode and decode vehicles. This works fine for basic decoding shown below.

```swift
let car = "{\"kind\": 0, \"brand\": \"Ford\", \"number_of_wheels\": 4}".data(using: .utf8)!
let motorCycle = "{\"kind\": 1, \"brand\": \"Yamaha\", \"number_of_wheels\": 2}".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

// Outputs a Project.Car
let ford = try! decoder.decode(Car.self, from: car)
// Outputs a Project.MotorCycle
let yamaha = try! decoder.decode(MotorCycle.self, from: motorCycle)
```

But what if I want to decode an array of vehicles, but have them decoded as a specific type?

```swift
let combined = "[{\"kind\": 0, \"brand\": \"Ford\", \"number_of_wheels\": 4}, {\"kind\": 1, \"brand\": \"Yamaha\", \"number_of_wheels\": 2}]".data(using: .utf8)!

// Outputs [Project.Vehicle, Project.Vehicle]
print(try! decoder.decode([Vehicle].self, from: combined))
```

How can I have the decoder output an array of vehicles, but typed vehicles, by using the kind property in the JSON data. As per example `[Project.Car, Project.MotorCycle]` if possible at all.

Comment: Nit picking perhaps but Vehicle is not a generic class but a superclass

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Ment superclass indeed

Comment: IMO you should simply drop the subclasses unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution that doesn't use `Codable`. Also I made some changes and introduced a protocol instead of a super class.

```
protocol Vehicle: CustomStringConvertible {
    var brand: String { get set }
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get set }
}

extension Vehicle {
    var description: String {
        "\(brand), wheels: \(numberOfWheels), type: \(type(of:self))"
    }
}
```

Not so important but I changed the types from class to struct

```
struct Car: Vehicle {
    var brand: String
    var numberOfWheels: Int
}

struct MotorCycle: Vehicle {
    var brand: String
    var numberOfWheels: Int
}
```

And then converted the json to a `Vehicle` array in two steps using `JSONSerialization` for the decoding and then `reduce(into:)` to create the objects

```
do {
    if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: combined) as? [[String: Any]] {
        let vehicles = array.reduce(into: [Vehicle]()) {
            if let kindValue = $1["kind"] as? Int,
               let kind = VehicleKind(rawValue: kindValue),
               let brand = $1["brand"] as? String,
               let numberOfWheels = $1["number_of_wheels"] as? Int {
                switch kind {
                case .car:
                    $0.append(Car(brand: brand, numberOfWheels: numberOfWheels))
                case .motorcycle:
                    $0.append(MotorCycle(brand: brand, numberOfWheels: numberOfWheels))
                }
            }
        }
        for vehicle in vehicles {
            print(vehicle)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The above code outputs:

> Ford, wheels: 4, type: Car
> Yamaha, wheels: 2, type: MotorCycle

---

**Update. Codable version**

I managed to come up with a Codable solution as well by introducing a separate type to use for decoding. The set up is the same as before with a protocol and two structs.

Then I introduce a specific type for decoding (but it can of course be extended for encoding as well) that implements a custom `init(from:)`

```
struct JsonVehicle: Decodable {
    let vehicle: Vehicle

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case kind
        case brand
        case numberOfWheels
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let kind = try container.decode(VehicleKind.self, forKey: .kind)
        let brand = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brand)
        let wheels = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .numberOfWheels)
        switch kind {
        case .car:
            vehicle = Car(brand: brand, numberOfWheels: wheels)
        case .motorcycle:
            vehicle = MotorCycle(brand: brand, numberOfWheels: wheels)
        }
    }
}
```

And again the end result is achieved in 2 steps

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    let result = try decoder.decode([JsonVehicle].self, from: combined)
    let vehicles = result.map(\.vehicle)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no kind property defined in class.
In addition, there is no difference between Car and MotorCycle
I tested this in playground, seems to do what you want.

```
    class Vehicle: Codable {
        enum Kind: Int, Codable {
            case car = 0, motorcycle = 1
        }
        let kind: Kind
        let brand: String
        let numberOfWheels: Int
    }
    
    class Car: Vehicle {}
    class MotorCycle: Vehicle {}

    let car = "{\"kind\": 0, \"brand\": \"Ford\", \"number_of_wheels\": 4}".data(using: .utf8)!
    let motorCycle = "{\"kind\": 1, \"brand\": \"Yamaha\", \"number_of_wheels\": 2}".data(using: .utf8)!
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    
    // Outputs a Project.Car
    let ford = try! decoder.decode(Car.self, from: car)
    // Outputs a Project.MotorCycle
    let yamaha = try! decoder.decode(MotorCycle.self, from: motorCycle)
    //But what if I want to decode an array of vehicles, but have them decoded as a specific type?
    
    let combined = "[{\"kind\": 0, \"brand\": \"Ford\", \"number_of_wheels\": 4}, {\"kind\": 1, \"brand\": \"Yamaha\", \"number_of_wheels\": 2}]".data(using: .utf8)!
    
    // Outputs [Project.Vehicle, Project.Vehicle]
    let allVeh = try! decoder.decode([Vehicle].self, from: combined)
    for veh in allVeh where veh.kind == Vehicle.Kind.motorcycle { // } is MotorCycle {
        print(veh.brand, type(of: veh))
    }
```

It gives:
Yamaha Vehicle

You could also write

```
let allMotorcycles = allVeh.filter {$0.kind == Vehicle.Kind.motorcycle}
for moto in allMotorcycles  {
    print(moto.brand, type(of: moto))
}
```

Comment: I believe the point of the question is to _not_ include `kind` as a property and only use it to determine what sub class to instantiate

Comment: What Joakim says indeed. The kind is needed in the JSON, but not in the object, as the class describes the kind. As for no difference in the two objects, that is simply due to it being an example. Practically speaking, the questions refers to a heterogenous array where each of the elements have a common superclass. Your example does not allow casting to type of MotorCycle as per request